# Power BI Transforming Data: How to get Account name instead of Account ID

Tags: schema, powerbi-desktop, data-transform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIlQp.png)

Im new to power BI, I have tried get data through dataverse and Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM. Both given the same issue as described in question#1.

Question #1
Most of the data show in the power query Editor(refer attached) is id instead of the text (valeu format as CRM user key in to the system, eg: show Account ID and cannot find Account Name, why will this happen and how do I get the human readable value instead  of ID?

Question #2:
(a) Why when i get data from Online source, ie. Microsoft Dynamics 365, many columes are blank although I remember I had input data into it on the CRM system.
(b) Can i create realtime visualization report by getting data using Microsoft Dynamics 365?

I need a solution, please help.